# Adicionar cabeçalho e rodapé em arquivo txt gerado via phptxt

Tags: php, txt

Esse script gera um txt extraído do MySQL:

```php
<?php

include "conexao.php";

$querymail = mysql_query("select cod,nome,tipo,valor from livros");
        fopen("txt/relatorio.txt", "w+");
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($querymail)) {
        $log = str_pad($data[0], 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $log1 = str_pad($data[1], 15, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        $log2 = str_pad($data[2], 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
                $log3 = str_pad($data[3], 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        if (!$savelog = fopen('txt/relatorio.txt', "a")) 
        { exit; }        
        if (!fwrite($savelog, $cod3. $log. $log1. $log2. $cod4b. $cod5b. $cod6b.  $log3. $cod7b. $cod8b."\r\n" ))
        { exit; fclose($savelog); }
        }
 ?>
```

O relatório gerado fica assim:

```
001   LIVRO01       AAAA      3200       
002   LIVRO02       AAAA      3200       
003   LIVRO03       AAAA      3200       
004   LIVRO04       AAAA      3200
```

Preciso inserir no topo do arquivo txt a data e horário (081120161226) e no rodapé o total de livro e valor total, assim:

```
081120161226

001   LIVRO01       AAAA      3200       
002   LIVRO02       AAAA      1200       
003   LIVRO03       AAAA      1000       
004   LIVRO04       AAAA      2500       

04 6900
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use um array para agrupar os dados na sequência correta, depois junte tudo com `join()` antes de escrever no arquivo;

```
<?php
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($querymail)) {
        $log = str_pad($data[0], 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $log1 = str_pad($data[1], 15, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        $log2 = str_pad($data[2], 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
                $log3 = str_pad($data[3], 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

        // Agrupe os valores num array ao invés de concatenar as strings, 
        // note o valor em branco na primeira posição
        $savelogs = array('', $cod3, $log, $log1, $log2, $cod4b, $cod5b, $cod6b, $log3, $cod7b, $cod8b);

        // pegue os totais que vai usar
        $totallivro = // total de livros;
        $valortotal = // total de livros;

        // Coloque a data na primeira posição do array
        array_unshift( $savelogs, date('dmYHs') );

        // Adicione mais uma linha em branco
        // e os totais ao final
        $savelogs[] = '';
        $savelogs[] = $totallivro.' '.$valortotal;

        // junte tudo numa string só
        $savelogs = join("\n", $savelogs);

        if (!$savelog = fopen('txt/relatorio.txt', "a")) 
        { exit; }        
        if (!fwrite($savelog, $savelogs."\r\n" ))
        { exit; fclose($savelog); }
        }
```

Comment: Não obtive êxito aplicando essa solução, obrigado!

Comment: qual erro vc teve @checktech?

Comment: Link para a solução funcionando: https://eval.in/674353. Substituí as suas variáveis por strings pra facilitar a visualização

Comment: <?php

include "conexao.php";

$querymail = mysql_query("select cod,nome,tipo,valor from livro");
        fopen("txt/relatorio.txt", "w+");
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($querymail)) {
        $log = str_pad($data[0], 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $log1 = str_pad($data[1], 40, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        $log2 = str_pad($data[2], 14, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $log3 = str_pad($data[3], 17, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

Comment: // Agrupe os valores num array ao invés de concatenar as strings, 
        // note o valor em branco na primeira posição
        $savelogs = array('', $cod3, $log, $log1, $log2, $cod4b, $cod5b, $cod6b, $log3, $cod7b, $cod8b);


        // pegue os totais que vai usar
        $totallivro = '20'; // total de livros;
        $valortotal = '0690'; // total de livros;

Comment: // Coloque a data na primeira posição do array
        array_unshift( $savelogs, date('dmYHs') );

        // Adicione mais uma linha em branco
        // e os totais ao final
        $savelogs[] = '';
        $savelogs[] = $totallivro.' '.$valortotal;

        // junte tudo numa string só
        $savelogs = join("\n", $savelogs);
        
        echo $savelogs;
 ?>

Comment: Não entendi. Você copiou o código do link. Funcionou pra você?

Comment: Copiei fiz as alterações e deu erro...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48189/discussion-between-checktech-and-ricardo-moraleida).

Answer (score 0):

Use um `fwrite` antes do `while` para escrever o cabeçalho; durante o `while` você vai acumulando quaisquer variáveis que você precise totalizar e, ao final, depois do final do `while`, você pode usar mais um `fwrite` para escrever os valores totais.

Obs: idealmente, você deveria abrir o arquivo apenas uma vez, e só fechar depois que tudo estiver escrito.

Comment: Testei fwrite, mas não consegui intercalar com while... Tem algum exemplo?

<?php
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, '1');
fwrite($fp, 'ou');
fwrite($fp, '2');
fclose($fp);

// o conteúdo de 'data.txt'será 1ou2!
?>